# Why is a lambda not-movable if it captures a not-copiable object using std::move()?

Tags: c++, function, lambda, c++14, move

Here is a sample code where I generate the error:

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

struct S {
    S() = default;
    S(const S&) = delete;
    S(S&&) = default;
    S& operator=(const S&) = delete;
    S& operator=(S&&) = delete;
};

template <typename F>
void post(F&& func)
{
    function<void()> f{forward<F>(func)};
}

int main()
{
    S s;
    post([s2 = move(s)] { });
}
```

Inside the lambda in `main()`, I capture the local variable `s` using `std::move()`. Before calling post(), `s2` must have been move constructed  successfully.

However, inside `post()`, `f` cannot be constructed with an rvalue reference to the type of this lambda.

If I remove, `s2 = move(s)`, `f` can be constructed with this rvalue reference.

Why does adding `s2 = move(s)` render the lambda not-movable?

Here, is a [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3bcc73046ec2bee) to try on coliru.

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc, please let me know why you disliked my question.

Comment: what makes you think I dislike it? I just put a tag for syntax highlighting

Comment: I am sorry, I misinterpreted the revision logs and thought you gave -1 to the question.

Comment: There is also the fact that S has constructors that take S instances rather than S references. I had to remove those to even get to the lambda.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, How? Can they coexist with `S(const S&) = delete`? Which ones are they?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir What are you talking about? There's no such constructor in `S`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your lambda does not become non-movable by having a move capture. But it does become non-copyable, which is a problem.

`std::function` does not support moving the supplied functor into itself, it always does a copy. Non-copyable lambdas (and other callables) therefore cannot be used with `std::function`. The reason for this limitation is that the standard requires `std::function` to be copyable, which could not be achieved if it was initialised with a non-copyable callable.

Comment: I tried `std::function<void()> f = []{}; auto f2 = move(f); f();` and `f()` threw `std::bad_function_call`. Does it disprove your statement that '`std::function` does not support moving the supplied functor into itself, it always does a copy.'?

Comment: @BenjiMizrahi No. You're confusing *moving a functor into `std::function`* with *moving the `std::function` object itself.* The former is not possible, while the latter is perfectly fine (and *moves* the stored functor, actually). The reason why the former is not possible is that the standard requires `std::function` to be copyable, which could not be achieved if it was constructible from a non-copyable functor.

Comment: @Angew is no longer proud of SO How copyable lambdas are converted to std::functions?By constructor of `std::function`?

Comment: @John Yes, specifically by constructor (5) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with your lambda, but with your object being non-copyable, since `std::function` demands its objects to be copyable the compiler complains. You should almost always follow the [rule-of-zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

In general:

- A lambda can be both copyable and moveable.
- If the lambda has non-copyable captures, it makes the the lambda itself not copyable. Those objects can be wrapped in a smart_pointer which can be moved (or copied - `shared_ptr`) in the lambda capture though.
- If there is no capture by value, the closure type (the lambda) is typically trivially copyable and trivially moveable.
- The closure type would be trivially copyable and trivially moveable if-and-only-if all captured by value objects are of trivially copyable and trivially moveable non-const types (eg C-like types).

  - Otherwise if there is capture by value, the move constructors of the closure type would copy the captured-by-value objects.
- If there is capture by value of a const object, any moves in the capture list would result in a copy.
- If the lambda itself is const it is never moved, only copied, even to other const lambdas.

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct S
{
    S() {
        std::cout << "ctor" << '\n';
    }
    ~S() noexcept {
        std::cout << "dtor" << '\n';
    }
    S(const S&) { 
        std::cout << "copy ctor\n";
    }
    S(S&&) noexcept noexcept {
        std::cout << "move ctor\n";
    }
    S& operator= (const S&) {
        std::cout << "copy aop\n";
    }
    S& operator= (S&&) noexcept {
        std::cout << "move aop\n";
    }
};

template <typename T>
void getTraits()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << "trivially_copy_constructible? "
        << std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<T>
        << "\ntrivially_move_constructible? "
        << std::is_trivially_move_constructible_v<T> << '\n' ;
}

int main()
{
    S s ;
    const S cs;
    {
        std::cout << "capture by value\n" ;
        //auto closure = [s = std::move(s)] {} ; // S::move construct               // 1.
        //auto closure = [cs = std::move(cs)] {} ; // S::copy construct             // 2.
        //const auto closure = [s = std::move(s)] {} ; // S::move construct         // 3.
        const auto closure = [cs = std::move(cs)] {} ; // S::copy construct         // 4.
        getTraits<decltype(closure)>();

        const auto copy_constructed = std::move(closure);
        const auto move_constructed = std::move(closure);
    }

    {
        std::cout << "\ncapture by reference\n";
        const auto closure = [&s] {};
        getTraits<decltype(closure)>();
    }
}
```

Uncomment 1, 2, 3, 4 one at a time and check the outputs. Remember `std::move` simply turns an object into an rvalue reference.

Comment: "Those objects can be wrapped in a smart_pointer which can be moved (or copied - shared_ptr) in the lambda capture though." Where is the smart_pointer?

Comment: "Otherwise if there is capture by value, the move constructors of the closure type would copy the captured-by-value objects."
This is false. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/ee9efYMG4, the copy constructor is not invoked once.